# Prevent more than one POST from an asp.net button on .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I have tried SO MANY different things... I am just wanting to prevent a user from clicking a button to submit a form more than one time. I have been trying to use javascript to stop the postback in various way but none of them work. Here's some code:

```
<form id="MyForm" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="FormPanel" runat="server">
             ...
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="Clicked(event)" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
            </asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            ...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</form>
<script>
    function Clicked(event) {
        alert('hello'); //this works!
        event.preventDefault();  //don't think this works...
        $('#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>').disabled = true;  //this didn't even work!
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", true)` - `$('#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>')` returns a jQuery object which has no `disabled` property

Comment: that didn't work. seems like it would, so I am trying to figure out why not

Comment: If you have jQuery included then this has to work. Without jQuery it would be `document.getElementById("<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>").disabled = true`

Comment: wait sorry - it totally works! i was just being stupid. so, are there any pitfalls to doing this?

Comment: Don't only rely on this functionality. This will only prevent the "regular" visitor from posting more than once. Javascript disabled, button re-enabled in the console/developer tools, resending the request with a intercept proxy,...

Comment: OK good thoughts. I think it'll be okay for an internal enterprise tool. I wouldn't rely on it in an actual product.